# Create an array from each line of a file in Ruby Rake

Tags: arrays, ruby, rake

I would like to create an array in Ruby rake called ARRAY where each line of an infile ("infile.txt") is an element of the array. 
This is how I have tried it so far:

```
desc "Create new array"
task :new_array do
ARRAY=Array.new
end

desc "Add elements to array"
task :add_elements => [:new_array] do
File.open("infile.txt").each do |line|
ARRAY.push(#{line})
end
end
```

However, I get the following error:

```
syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting ')'
```

for the end after "`ARRAY.push(#{line})`"

Can someone explain to me what the problem is or let me know of another way to do this?

Many thanks!

Comment: It seems like the syntax error is coming from the argument being passed to `#push` - you're passing in a string interpolation of `line`, but not wrapping it in a string. Try changing it to `"#{line}"`.

Comment: You mean [`IO::readlines`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/IO.html#method-c-readlines) e.g. `File.readlines("infile.txt")`

Comment: @engineersmnky I did not want to use this as I get symbols for newlines at the end of each of the array elements, which I do not want. Although there are probably ways to remove those (using chomp as suggested below, for example). Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Very well then `File.foreach("infile.txt").map {|line| line.chomp }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you're trying to use string interpolation (`#{...}`) outside a string:

```
ARRAY.push(#{line})
# ---------^^^^^^^
```

You could use string interpolation by throwing in some double quotes:

```
ARRAY.push("#{line}")
```

but there's no need to convert a string (`line`) to an identical string (`"#{line}"`) so you could just push straight onto the array:

```
ARRAY.push(line)
```

Or you could just skip all that explicit iteration and use `#to_a`:

```
array = File.open("infile.txt").to_a
```

And if you wanted to strip off the newlines:

```
array = File.open('infile.txt').map(&:chomp)
```

---

As [engineersmnky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1978251/engineersmnky) points out in the comments, using [`File.readlines`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/IO.html#method-c-readlines) would be a better approach:

```
array = File.readlines('infile.txt')
array = File.readlines('infile.txt').map(&:chomp)
#...
```

And don't forget to check [`IO`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/IO.html) as well as [`File`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/File.html) for methods when working with files.

Comment: In the final 2 options presented the file will remain `open` because a block is not passed to `open` and since it remains unassigned you will have to wait for GC to collect it before it is closed.  Maybe instead use `File.readlines('infile.txt')` for the first and `File.open('infile.txt') { |f| f.map(&:chomp) }` or `File.foreach('infile.txt').map(&:chomp)` for the second.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this:

```
array = []

IO.foreach("path/to/file.txt") { |line|

  array.push(line.chomp)

}
```

Then if you want to clear the array from empty lines just use delete:

```
array.delete("")
```